# Using datepicker in MVC 4.0 to persist a date value in db, throwing "object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Working around with MVC 4.0/Razor as the view engine.

Scenario: Binding a calendar to a text box, clicking in the txtBox should let a calendar flow down,using jqueryUI's datepicker and submitting it to a sql db.

What I did:

Model class:

```
    public class UserModels
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mandatory Field")]
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public virtual DateTime Dob { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "CountrY")]
        public virtual string Country { get; set; }
        public virtual string Gender { get; set; }


    }
```

Razor View:

```
@model EMSapp.Models.UserModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddUser";
}
<h2>AddUser</h2>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#date").datepicker();

    }); 
    </script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>UserModels</legend>
         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dob)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">

            @**Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dob, new { id = "date" })**   

        </div>
```

Error: When is the view is loading, "object doesn't support this property or method" is thrown.

Comment: Please post `EMSapp.Models.UserModels`.

Comment: Oops Missed it, you can find it now.

Answer (score 0):

`Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dob, new { id = "date" })` should be setting the `name` and `id` attributes of your textbox to "Dob".

Try calling `Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Dob)` and using `$('#Dob').datepicker();` instead.

Comment: The result still is the same! moreover, more over i am setting the txtBox id to date. Why is it that Dob w.r.t you.

Comment: What browser are you using? Maybe it has something to do with `TextBoxFor` setting the input to `type="datetime"`? I am assuming this is a javascript error you're getting, no?

Comment: IE 9. Yea i suspect the same, but unable to figure it out.